# SQL Server: Alter a clustered primary index to an non-clustered

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing

How do I alter a primary clustered index to become a non-clustured index. (Being a "secondary" table I want to use the clustured index for the foreign key column of the "header" table.)

This doen't work for me (error seems reasonable :)

```
DROP INDEX ClientUsers.PK_ClientUsers
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_ClientUsers_Id ON ClientUsers(Id)

Msg 3723, Level 16, State 4, Line 7
An explicit DROP INDEX is not allowed on index 'ClientUsers.PK_ClientUsers'. 
It is being used for PRIMARY KEY constraint enforcement.
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping the primary key constraint first?

ALTER TABLE ClientUsers DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ClientUsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have to:

1. Drop the FK
2. Drop the PK
3. Drop the clustered index
4. Recreate the PK
5. Recreate the FK
6. Recreate the clustered index on the FK column

and then optionally create a secondry index on the PK column

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried dropping the PRIMARY KEY constraint on the table as well - then dropping the index - then re-adding both?

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP primary key
```

Comment: won't  that be a problem if he has an FK

Comment: Possibly, but the question wasn't clear if the foreign key was set up on this column yet - I was just addressing the immediate problem.

If we're worried about foreign keys, we need to think about ALL foreign keys. That may be many foreign keys dependent on this column: could be a lot of foreign key destruction/reinstantiation required.